# Need information on the following multi-group homomorphic structure

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, group-homomorphism

For the sake of simplicity I will describe the problem with a three group structure.

Suppose there are three groups $G_1$, $G_2$ and $G_3$. Suppose also there is a binary map $M:G_1\times G_2\to G_3$ so that

1. For all $g_2$ in $G_2$, $M(\_,g_2):G_1 \to G_3$ is a homomorphism.
2. For all $g_1$ in $G_1$, $M(g_1,\_) : G_2 \to G_3$ is a homomorphism.
3. For all $g_1$ and $g_1'$, $M(g_1,\_)*M(g_1',\_)$ is the homomorphism $M(g_1*g_1',\_)$
   and similarly for all $g_2,g_2'$.

I have encountered this structure and am looking for references and results for this structure.

Comment: I believe the last condition is actually redundant with the first two. Indeed, $M(g_1,g_2)*M(g_1',g_2)=M(g_1*g_1',g_2)$ for all $g_1,g_1'\in G_1$ and all $g_2\in G$ if $M(\_,g_2)$ is a group homomorphism. But I am not 100% sure I understand what you mean...

Answer (score 1):

The third condition is implied by the first two. You can call such a map [bilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_map), although that term is more commonly used when $G_1, G_2, G_3$ are all abelian.

Note that this condition is stronger than it looks in the nonabelian case. We have

$$M(ab, cd) = M(a, cd) M(b, cd) = M(a, c) M(a, d) M(b, c) M(b, d)$$

but we also have

$$M(ab, cd) = M(ab, c) M(ab, d) = M(a, c) M(b, c) M(a, d) M(b, d)$$

from which it follows that $M(a, d) M(b, c) = M(b, c) M(a, d)$ for all $a, b, c, d$. In other words, the image of $M$ is necessarily an abelian subgroup of $G_3$, and so $M$ factors through the abelianizations of $G_1$ and $G_2$. This shows that there is a "tensor product" $G_1 \otimes G_2$ such that bilinear maps correspond to homomorphisms $G_1 \otimes G_2 \to G_3$, but it's just the tensor product of the abelianizations of $G_1$ and $G_2$.